# Aptana plugin Debug rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I'm tring to debug a rails project using aptana studio 3 pluging

I've run the command

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

When i select Debug Server of the contextual menu of the project i get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta9/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta9/bin/rdebug-ide:17:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta9/bin/rdebug-ide:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@miGemSet/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
```

By the way my O.S is Fedora 16

Any of you knows what that means?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue with Ubuntu 12.04, and did 2 things:

1- Sent an e-mail asking for help.
2- Install RubyMine

On both results the issue is some gems that are missing.

linecache19 (0.5.13 from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=46302)
ruby-debug-base19x (gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre)
ruby-debug-ide (gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre)

Thanks to Denis Usahkov for the help :D

Comment: thanks very much. You help me a lot. If you have the same problem also look at http://rails.vandenabeele.com/blog/2011/12/21/installing-ruby-debug19-with-ruby-1-dot-9-3-on-rvm/

Comment: I trying RubyMine and its solve a lot of issues I was having with Aptana. For me (I'm learning RoR and I don't want to start a flamewar) is the best IDE, and I also tried Netbeans on both Windows and Ubuntu. Any way thanks for the link, is a very nice blog :)

Answer (score 0):

I donwloaded the gems from the link above (http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=46302), then I did the following:

```
rvm fetch 1.9.3
gem install ~/Downloads/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install ~/Downloads/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/home/bruno.medeiros/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/
```

The server started properly, but the Aptana don't stop on break points yet.